# Как использовать элемент как переключатель вкладок внутри страницы

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap, material-design

[image: Внешний вид элемента]

Использую эти [наработки](http://demos.creative-tim.com/material-kit/index.html?ref=material-dashboard) 
Можно заметить что используется атрибут data-toggle, я думаю можно построить взаимодействие через него

Пример кода:

```
<div>
                        <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-pills-primary" role=   "tablist">
                            <li>
                                <a href="#dashboard" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
                                    <i class="material-icons">dashboard</i>
                                    Dashboard
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="active">
                                <a href="#schedule" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
                                    <i class="material-icons">schedule</i>
                                    Schedule
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#tasks" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
                                    <i class="material-icons">list</i>
                                    Tasks
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#tasks" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
                                    <i class="material-icons">list</i>
                                    Tasks
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#tasks" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
                                    <i class="material-icons">list</i>
                                    Tasks
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Нужно чтобы оно работало примерно как бутстраповские Toggleable / Dynamic Pills

Comment: Добавьте пожалуйста пример вашего кода и как-то более подробно опишите желаемый результат.